# What is use of Datanavigateurlformatstring of hyperlink in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, format-string, navigateurl

How to use `Datanavigateurlformatstring` of hyperlink in `gridview`?

I want to display page with the name of product like

http://localhost:55724/Admin/Category/Update/computer when I clicked on computer in gridview, it says `resource not found`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"> 
    <Columns> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Id" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="id" 
                            DataTextField="Productname" 
                            HeaderText="Product" 
                            Target="_blank" 
                            NavigateUrl="Searchdetails.aspx?product={0}" 
                            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Product/Searchdetails.aspx?product={0}" /> 
    </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

How to fix this error.

Comment: The url youi provided is valid only in your computer. Post some code so that we can better help you with your error

Comment: Please edit your question to add and format your code, it is not readable as a comment

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Id" />
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="id" DataTextField="Productname" HeaderText="Product" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl="Searchdetails.aspx?product={0}" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Product/Searchdetails.aspx?product={0}" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView> . This code is formatted id visual studio.@Tasos K. Can U help me?

Comment: Try and remove the `NavigateUrl="Searchdetails.aspx?product={0}" ` property